# Is a set of rotations and translations of the plane a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, linear-transformations

I'm having some trouble understanding the definition of a group of matrices given in the paper [Group Equivariant Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07576.pdf).
In Section 4.2, the authors define the group p4 (of translations and rotations by multiples of $\pi/2$ around any point in the plane):

> The group p4 consists of all compositions of translations
> and rotations by 90 degrees about any center of rotation in
> a square grid.

They then parametrize the elements of p4 as follows:

> A convenient parameterization of this group
> in terms of three integers r, u, v is:
> $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     \cos(r\pi / 2)       & -\sin(r\pi / 2) & u \\
>     \sin(r\pi / 2)       & \cos(r\pi / 2) & v \\
>     0       & 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

This set of matrices that are parametrized by (r, u, v) surely generates p4, but I'm not sure how is it a parametrization of the group (is it even closed to composition?).
To my understanding, an $(r, u, v)$-matrix will rotate by $r\pi/2$ (around zero) and then shift by $(u, v)$.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a mistake in the paper?

(this question applies to the group p4m in the following section 4.3 as well, where the parametrized matrices seem to define the action of the Dihedral group $D_4$ followed by a shift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is closed under composition. That is not hard to check directly. This group acts exactly as you have described on the plane $z=1$.

This comes from the standard way to express the affine group as a linear group. In general, the $n$-dimensional affine group over $k$ is $G=\operatorname{GL_n}(k)\ltimes k^n$ and it isomorphic to the linear group of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}M & v\\ 0\ldots 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, where $M\in \operatorname{GL_n}(k)$ and $v\in k^n$. The standard action of the affine group on $k^n$ is the same as the action of the linear group on the plane $x_{n+1}=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tomasz, sorry, but I still don't see how this answers my question about the parametrization though. Can *every* element in this group be parametrized by three integers as they claim?

Comment: It actually turns out to be translation by [-a,-a]. But I see my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @sillyme: Right, of course. It should be either $[-a,-a]$ or $[a,a]$.